# Npm install not working - reify stalled - but works on other machines. How to investigate further /fix

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have a problem with npm on a server (cloudlinux with node 16 and npm 8.15). When trying to install via `npm ci` it just stalls and seems to be doing nothing anymore on my server. I tried it with `--verbose` option to see if I get any errors but I don't.

```
... # lots of dependencies installed
npm timing build:link:node_modules/which Completed in 26ms
npm timing build:link:node_modules/webpack-dev-server Completed in 26ms
npm timing build:link:node_modules/execa/node_modules/which Completed in 25ms
npm timing build:link:node_modules/pinia/node_modules/vue-demi Completed in 25ms
npm timing build:link Completed in 33ms
npm info run canvas@2.10.1 install node_modules/canvas node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --update-binary
npm info run yorkie@2.0.0 install node_modules/yorkie node bin/install.js
npm info run canvas@2.10.1 install { code: 134, signal: null }
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/canvas
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/nan
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/simple-get
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/detect-libc
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/nopt
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/npmlog
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/semver
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/tar
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/decompress-response
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/simple-concat
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/abbrev
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/are-we-there-yet
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/console-control-strings
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/gauge
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/set-blocking
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/chownr
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/fs-minipass
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/minizlib
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/mimic-response
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/delegates
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/aproba
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/color-support
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/has-unicode
npm verb reify failed optional dependency /home/dasdding/m3d/node_modules/wide-align
npm timing build:run:install:node_modules/canvas Completed in 660ms
[##################] | reify:typescript: timing build:run:install:node_modules/canvas Completed in 660ms
```

It's been stalled there for >10min and also retries or `npm cache clean --force` did not help.
Weirdly it works locally on my dev machine (windows) and on gitlab-ci (linux docker), so must be somehow infrastructure related. However I don't know where to investigate further.

Ideas?
Cheers
Tom

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Turned out to be an ipv6 issue. To work around it,

1. disable ipv6 on your machine
2. use npm
3. re-enable ipv6 on your machine

on mac, you can do it in preferences or from cli. quick google search will show you how